# Postfix will not send/receive mail [fatal: open database … No such file or directory]

Tags: email, debian, localhost, telnet, postfix

I recently installed postfix, among other programs, and have been configuring it. POP3 and IMAP are working just fine, but postfix seems to fail:

> # telnet localhost 25
> Trying ::1...
> Trying 127.0.0.1...
> Connected to localhost.
> Escape character is '^]'.
> ehlo localhost

Not only does this render PuTTY unusable (server doesn't respond to any commands), but I also checked `syslog` and this is what I found:

> postfix/smtpd[7248]: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders.db: No such file or directory
> postfix/master[1582]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 7248 exit status 1
> postfix/master[1582]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling

This sequence seems to be endlessly repeating.

So, what should I do to make sure postfix works properly?

Answer (score 1):

```
postfix/smtpd[7248]: fatal: open database /etc/postfix/controlled_envelope_senders.db: No such file or directory
```

Use `postmap` command to compile `controlled_envelope_senders` file into `d_envelope_senders.db` file.

Comment: How would I do this? Neither of those files exist.

Comment: So you have postfix configuration you do not understand. If you are brave then you may create empty `controlled_envelope_sender` file and compile it using `postmap`. I would strongly suggest an attempt to understand what the controlled_envelope_senders is suppodes to deliver.

Comment: Did that, and now I'm getting an `invalid argument` error.